# Full coherence for non-symmetric linearly distributive categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, linear-logic, coherence, string-diagrams

**1. Context**
Mac Lane's coherence theorem for monoidal categories can be phrased as "every formal diagram in a monoidal category commutes.“ I am interested in this type of coherence question for linearly distributive categories.
In [*Natural deduction and coherence for weakly distributive categories*](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/rags/nets/nets.pdf) Blute et al. give a full decision procedure for the equality of morphisms in free symmetric linearly distributive categories. Later Schneck in [*Natural deduction and coherence for non-symmetric linearly distributive categories*](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/6/n9/6-09abs.html) modifies their result to obtain a (partial) decision procedure for morphisms in free non-symmetric linearly distributive categories. In the context of non-symmetric linearly distributive categories, in all instances in which I tried to apply Schneck‘s/Blute‘s result, the two morphisms I considered, turned out to be equal (i.e. the two proof nets turned out to be surgically equivalent).

**2. Question**
This leads me to wonder:

- Does any formal diagram (diagram consisting only of distributors, associators, unitors and not using any relations between morphisms or objects that are not forced by the linearly distributive structure) in a non-symmetric linearly distributive category commute?
- If one believes in Schneck‘s and Blute‘s graphical calculus, this question can be rephrased as: Are any two planar proof nets (without non-logical axioms) with one and the same input and one and the same output (which are both additionally surgically equivalent to a net obtained by juxtaposition, $\otimes$-tensoring or $\oplus$-tensoring of nets corresponding to the unitors, associators or distributors) surgically equivalent as nets?

**3. Thoughts**
I would guess that this is false (wouldn't the authors of above papers have mentioned this claim at least as a conjecture otherwise?).
I tried looking for two inequivalent reduced normal forms of proof nets with the same input/output — to no avail. For symmetric linearly distributive categories an example of non-equal morphisms is given by the twist $\tau: \top \oplus \top \rightarrow \top \oplus \top$ and the identity $\operatorname{id}: \top \oplus \top \rightarrow \top \oplus \top$ (see page 258 in Blute et al.). If one allows the existence of non-logical axioms ("extra components" in the language of proof nets), there are again examples (see page 142 Schneck or for instance "the triple-dual problem" on page 275 Blute et al.).